# Multiple File Upload on PHP for IIS

Tags: php, iis

I have PHP 7 installed on my IIS server. My target is to upload multiple files to the server. (submit is done through javascript)

Every time I submit, I get an echo of 0, stating that there are no files uploaded. What am I doing wrong? Is there anything wrong with the PHP or is it an IIS thing?

HTML Form:

```
<form action="/fileupload.php" id="form" style="display: none;" method="post"><input type="file" id="fileToUpload[]" name="file" multiple></form>
```

fileupload.php:

```
<?php
$total = count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
echo $total;
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i];
    $file_size =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'][$i];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $file_type=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'][$i];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i])));

    $expensions= array("pdf","doc","docx","xls","xlsx","ppt","pptx");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="Extension not allowed.";
    }

    if($file_size > 20971520){
        $errors[]="File too large.";
    }

    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"D:/charity/".$file_name);
        echo "Thanks for sharing.";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "D:/"!
You are trying to move the files to a LOCAL path ("D:/charity/"). Move_uploaded_file only works server side as far as I know. That means the destination folder must be on the server. Your path to the folder will depend on where you have your "fileupload.php" file.

If you are using a local server on your computer, it does not matter, you still can't use the local path. If you have created a subfolder (e.g. "charity") that is in the same folder where you have the file "fileupload.php", then your upload path will be "charity/".$file_name.

: P
/MacD